# Left ideals of a ring of matrices

Tags: matrices, ideals

Let's consider the ring $R = \begin{bmatrix}\Bbb{Z} & 0\\\Bbb{Q} & \Bbb{Q}\end{bmatrix} = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix}z & 0\\q & p\end{bmatrix}\mid z \in \Bbb{Z}, p, q \in \Bbb{Q}\right\}$.

I want to prove that if $I$ is a left ideal of $R$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\\Bbb{Q} & \Bbb{Q}\end{bmatrix} \subseteq I$, then $I = \begin{bmatrix}z\Bbb{Z} & 0\\\Bbb{Q} & \Bbb{Q}\end{bmatrix}$ for some $z \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: consider the set $K$ of integers $a$ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\in I
$$
and prove it is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then prove that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
K & 0 \\
\mathbb{Q} & \mathbb{Q}
\end{bmatrix}=I
$$

Comment: Ok, I have proved that K is an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$. But how can I show that the last set is equal to $I$?

Comment: @effezeta One inclusion is obvious. For the other one, use the inclusion in the assumptions and the fact that $I$ is a left ideal.